# jQuery: easier way to use .clone() than described below?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, clone

If you execute in the console on this page

```
var cloned = $(".question").clone(true);
$(".question").addClass("first");
var clonedStr = cloned[0].outerHTML || new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(cloned[0]);
$(".question").after(clonedStr);
```

you will clone the question (there will be two questions on the page, but the first one will be with the `.first` class). That's what is needed.

Is there any simpler way to do this with jQuery? I'm confused of the third string in the code above and believe it could be simpler. Any ideas?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't use the HTML as string, then don't get it. Just use the jQuery object:

```
var cloned = $(".question").clone(true);
$(".question").addClass("first").after(cloned);
```

Also, you can do it one line:

```
$(".question").after($(".question").clone(true)).first().addClass("first");
```

Comment: @Rort McCrossan: thank you Rort McCrossan and Ionică Bizău for both answers. Why did you removed you answer? It this one better as it is shorter?

Comment: @Haradzieniec I was just checking something, I thought my answer was incorrect but it works fine. Mine is a line longer as I cache the `.question` selector

Comment: @Rory McCrossan thank you very much for your trial and your further explanation!

Comment: @Haradzieniec *Measuring programming progress by lines of code is like measuring aircraft building progress by weight.* -- Bill Gates. :-) It's better to use with objects than with strings. Since you have the jQuery object there, you don't need to get the HTML and insert it. Note that inserting the HTML manually, will make the even handlers dissapear.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `insertAfter` to insert the cloned element after changing the class. You don't need to convert the element in the jQuery object to a string, you can use that object within the function itself:

```
var $question = $('.question');
var $cloned = $question.clone(true).insertAfter($question);
$question.addClass('first');
```